# Single Responsibility Principle - chessboard piece

Tags: design-patterns, chess, single-responsibility-principle

Applying the single responsibility principle to a chessboard application, what should a Piece interface/class be responsible for?

I am sure it needs to know its colour, type and valid moves.  But should it also know its position (x/y) in the board?  Or, should the board know the position of each piece.

This decision also has some consequences on how the piece can move in that, does the board decide what a valid move is for a piece etc

Comment: You may be interested in this series of Eric Lippert's: http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/.  He examines the pattern of encoding game rules as properties and methods of game characters, and ultimately rejects it as unsuitable.  The valid moves for a given piece, for example, should be represented in the object model by *rule* objects or the like. (This would also make it much easier to enable your program to handle Chess960 or another [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_variants)).

Comment: Can you specify the responsibilities in terms of behaviors instead of knowledge? If a piece knows its position, what is the behavior that needs to know about the position? Similar for the board. Btw, you might want to read this very good article about SRP: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to think you might want to make PieceOnBoard a different entity than Piece.

There are a couple of ways to do it-- but generally you want to separate the aspects that apply to a Rook in general, say, from a specific Rook as it is participating in a particular chess game.

You could make Piece be an interface that determines valid moves given a PieceOnBoad and a BoardPosition-- it could have implementations specific to the different kinds of chess pieces.  The implementation of this class for "Rook" would correspond to "Rook in General".

A PieceOnBoard would be a composite of a Piece, a Color and a BoardPosition.  A particular instance of PieceOnBoard would correspond to a particular rook participating in a particular chess game.

Then a BoardPosition could be merely a collection of PieceOnBoard objects.